# Django forms.form returning empty choice list

Tags: django

I have my choices added through the **init** method for a given forms.form as shown below:

```
def __init__(self, user, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductColorVariationsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["photo"].required = False
        files =  ()
        for file in instance.files.all():
            files = files + ((file.id, file.file.url),)
        self.fields['photo'].choices = files
```

In the template, I have the select list items as expected.
[image]
However, I am unable to validate the form as it complains of the selected value not being in the available choices.

Printing out the choices in the custom widget, gives me an empty tuple.

```
class JQSelectMenuInputWidget(Select):
    template_name = "widgets/jqselectmenu.html"
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=(), disabled_choices=()):
        super(JQSelectMenuInputWidget, self).__init__(attrs, choices=choices)
        self.disabled_choices = disabled_choices
        print(choices)
```

So my question is, why is it that the choices that are set in the **init** method not being pass down the widget class.

Comment: What is `photo`? Can you share the field?

Comment: Here is the photo field ```photo = JQSelectInputField(widget=JQSelectMenuInputWidget(attrs={"class": "photo","placeholder": _("Select Photo"), "autocomplete": "off","name":'id_photo' }) )```

Answer (score 0):

You are not working with the widget, but with the form field, you use `.widget` to access the widget:

```
def __init__(self, user, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['photo'].required = False
    if instance.files:
        self.fields['photo'].widget.choices = [
            (file.id, file.file.url) for file in instance.files.all()
        ]
```

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.

Comment: The ```photo``` field is a custom field, ```photo = JQSelectInputField(widget=JQSelectMenuInputWidget(attrs={
                "class": "photo",
                "placeholder": _("Select Photo"),
                "autocomplete": "off",
                "name": 'id_photo'
            }) )``` I think the problem is that choices passed through __init__ aren't available for the widget. Because passing some choices directly into the field above will yield choices in the widget. Thank you